# Swagger / Fetch errorService Unavailable /swagger/v1/swagger.json ERROR

Tags: .net, swagger

I want to open swagger in .net core project without using localhost. There is a website url link.

I got an error **Fetch error Service Unavailable /swagger/v1/swagger.json.**
(By the way, If I run this project in localhost, It works.)

[image: 1]

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: in my case, some functions don't declared http method or wrong setting public/private function

Comment: thank you for comment, I am going to control again.